# What is the purpose of the various qiskit libraries?

Tags: qiskit

I can't find much resources about how `Qiskit` API libraries are organised. We could see versions by using:

```
import qiskit 
print(qiskit.__qiskit_version__)
>> {'qiskit-terra': '0.21.2',
 'qiskit-aer': '0.10.4',
 'qiskit-ignis': None,
 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.19.2',
 'qiskit': '0.37.2',
 'qiskit-nature': None,
 'qiskit-finance': None,
 'qiskit-optimization': None,
 'qiskit-machine-learning': None}
```

What is the purpose of these libraries?

Comment: This blogpost from Qiskit's official blog contains a good overview: https://medium.com/qiskit/what-is-qiskit-your-guide-to-navigating-the-qiskit-cosmos-in-2022-7cc415426f31

Comment: If the images are public licensed, please consider converting comment to answer. @Egretta.Thula

Comment: @luciano Yes nicely !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-terra` is the "core" of `qiskit`, containing things like the circuit class, gates, etc. `-aer` contains circuit simulators to test out your circuit. `-ignis` is for noise modeling, containing various error channels and quantum information and error correction utilities. `-ibmq-provider` is for running on the IBM cloud, be it QPUs or hosted simulators. *Note: `-ignis` has been superseded by `qiskit-experiments`, as in @Egretta.Thula'a comment.*

`qiskit` itself just packages everything together. `-nature`, `-finance`, `-optimization`, and `-machine-learning` are pretty self explanatory, containing tools to express problems in their respective domains as quantum programs.